# Delayed Job One worker for one task (synchronous call)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have `20 Delayed job workers`

I had search so many links and post for `synchronous` processing for that job but nothing works for me

Also assign `QUEUE` for perticular `worker` like this

**`script/delayed_job --queue=order_item_kit start -i 0`**

**`order.delay(:queue => "order_item_kit").update_order`**
But this will assign to this queue and other worker also works for it.

I am searching for `one worker` will run `one job` at a time.
for this particular  case

Please give suggestion to work for this case, one method calls only one worker as a time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As i understand, 20 instances of worker have been started and now you need to make sure specific queue is being processed by a specific worker

Comment: Yes, after it gets complete than again it assign to that worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solve this by doing that way

When it assign next same job to another worker, we can add `run_at` one second ahead, so `multiple workers` does not save object same time and this fix our issue

```
latest_job = Delayed::Job.where(queue: "order_item_kit").last

run_at = latest_job ? latest_job.run_at + 1.seconds : 1.seconds.from_now

kit_sku.delay(:run_at => run_at,:queue =>"order_item_kit").update_ordere_item
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the DJ [documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

> Processes started without specifying a queue will run jobs from any queue.

You should run your workers with explicit queue name:
`RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=tracking start`

And with some other queue name for all other ('default') workers.
To define that name set `Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name` in initializer.

Comment: Yes done with explicit queue name but it not works because it doesnot allow other worker to run for this but other worker runs these delay method

Comment: If you want to have 2 queues, one for that task, another for all other tasks, you need to define _default_ queue name and run first worker with special queue name, and other workers with default queue name